# Creating sql connections multiple times in loop causes to drop connection

Tags: mysql, sql, shell

I have one csv file. I am reading userId from it.It has around 30,000 users.

I have created one shell script to read that csv and search for that users in mysql database
and use that info to grab user related data from other tables.

I am running follwing kinds of query multiple times

```
       mysql -uUserId -ppwd -hlocalhost -Pportno databaseName -e "Select *from UserInfo where UserName='Test'"
```

Its causing to drop the mysql connection after certain entries and automatically reconnecting.

Some entires get searched and some entries not.

Does Select query in loop for multiple times cause this problem
Any solution for it.

Comment: Can you post the whole script ? I think you should connect once then request.

Comment: @iPouf:sorry I can't.If u need any more info I can provide

Comment: A better approach may be to load the values from the CSV into a table, then join the tables in a query to obtain the matches.

Comment: @Turophile : I searched for it I found that I can try with persistant connection. Anybody has idea about it?